# What is the difference between deem and consider?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

According to Cambridge Dictionary, deem is defined as a way to "to consider or judge something in a particular way". However, I'm not sure if there is any subtle difference in meaning or connotation of deem and consider.

Another question, is there any difference if I use either one of these phrases or the latter is simply more concise?

> is considered/deemed to be adj
>
> is considered/deemed adj

Answer (score 3):

They mean the same thing **but are used in different contexts**.

- deem is used in contracts and legal language (legal briefs, etc.) and is generally used in written texts. **It is not used verbally as much** as it is **very formal**.
- consider is used everywhere: in speech and in writing.

That is the only difference I know.